# "No space left on device" and "You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/."

Tags: apt, partitioning, package-management, mount

I'm using an ubuntu 18.04 docker container. I am facing not enough space error.

$`cat /etc/lsb-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

When I try training a resnext101 model from torchvision, I get the following error.

```
Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnext101_32x8d-8ba56ff5.pth" to /home/vmuser/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints/resnext101_32x8d-8ba56ff5.pth
  0%|                                                          | 0.00/340M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_attn_best_config.py", line 377, in <module>
    tabct = TabCT(cnn = model, fc_dim = fd, attn_filters = af, n_attn_layers = nal).to(gpu)
  File "train_attn_best_config.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.ct_cnn = cnn_dict[cnn](pretrained = True)
  File "/home/vmuser/anaconda3/envs/pulmo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py", line 317, in resnext101_32x8d
    pretrained, progress, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vmuser/anaconda3/envs/pulmo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py", line 227, in _resnet
    progress=progress)
  File "/home/vmuser/anaconda3/envs/pulmo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 481, in load_state_dict_from_url
    download_url_to_file(url, cached_file, hash_prefix, progress=progress)
  File "/home/vmuser/anaconda3/envs/pulmo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 404, in download_url_to_file
    f.write(buffer)
  File "/home/vmuser/anaconda3/envs/pulmo/lib/python3.7/tempfile.py", line 481, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

When I run `df`, I get this, one of my tmpfs is only 65 mb. I tried running `export TMPDIR=/var/tmp` and `export TMPDIR=~/Data/tmp`

$`df`

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay        1797272568 1705953392         0 100% /
tmpfs               65536          0     65536   0% /dev
tmpfs            98346264          0  98346264   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6      1797272568 1705953392         0 100% /etc/hosts
shm                 65536          0     65536   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1      1845816492 1362932848 389098592  78% /home/vmuser/Data
tmpfs            98346264         12  98346252   1% /proc/driver/nvidia
tmpfs            19669256      93256  19576000   1% /run/nvidia-persistenced/socket
udev             98318592          0  98318592   0% /dev/nvidia1
tmpfs            98346264          0  98346264   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            98346264          0  98346264   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs            98346264          0  98346264   0% /sys/firmware
```

But the error is still there.

When I try to upgrade any packages, I get another error:
`E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.`

When I run,
`sudo du -hsc /var/cache`

```
1.6M    /var/cache
1.6M    total
```

There is very little space in my /var/cache.

I tried `clean`, `autoclean`, `clean packages`, symbolic link `sudo ln -s /home/apt/ /var/cache/apt`, but still facing these errors.

Comment: You can symbolic link your /var/cache to the other drive

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Your text description implies a *snap* only release (18) and not a *deb* based release like 18.04 which is a different product. Ubuntu has used *yy* releases since 2016 to mean *snap* only specialist releases (they don't use `apt` but `snap`)

Answer (score 0):

If your Docker container is using DeviceMapper, Btrfs, overlay2, WindowsFilter, or ZFS Graph drivers, then you could do something like this when defining a container:

```
docker run -it --storage-opt size=500G torchy /bin/bash
```

***Note:** Be sure to change `torchy` to the proper container name.*

This will allow to set the container’s root file system size to 500G at creation time. Just as with many virtual machine tools, you do not need to preallocate the space when defining it.

#### Caveats

1. When using DeviceMapper, Btrfs, WindowsFilter or ZFS Graph drivers, you cannot pass a size less than the Default BaseFS size (which is usually 10G)
2. When using the overlay2 storage driver, the size option is only available if the backing file system is XFS and mounted with the `pquota` mount option. Under these conditions, you can pass any size less then the backing file system size.

For more info, [the docs are your friend](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-storage-driver-options-per-container)